# How to login to indeed with Python?

Tags: python

I am trying to loggin to my Indeed account using python in order to automate my work. I want to access all the candidates that have apply to my job offer.

However I am stuck in the development of this program.

In fact Indeed has a captcha validation therefore I am login to indeed on my browser and I get the cookies of the session on Python. However I face again a new challenge is that Java needs to be enable.

That's what I tried:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

session = requests.Session()

response = session.get('https://www.indeed.com/')
cookies = session.cookies.get_dict()

url = 'https://employers.indeed.com/m#dashboard'
page = requests.get(url, cookies=cookies).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')

print(soup)
```

And I get this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"/><meta content="noindex" name="robots"/></head><body><script type="text/javascript">
var i, t, p, L=location.href, ps=L.split(/[&?]/);
for (i=0; i<ps.length; i++) {
  if (ps[i].indexOf("token=") == 0) {
    t = ps[i].substring(6);
  }
}
if(!t){
  i=L.indexOf('#');
  t=encodeURIComponent(i<0?'':L.substring(i+1));
}
p=location.pathname.substring(1, 2);
var d=encodeURIComponent(p+'?token='+t);
window.location='/account/login?dest='+d;

</script><noscript>JavaScript is required. Please enable it in your web browser.</noscript></body></html>
```

Comment: It looks like Indeed has an API available that might make your life a little easier. https://opensource.indeedeng.io/api-documentation/

Comment: I looked at that but there is no API to get the candidates that applied for the job I posted. Also I tried to dig with selenium but it seems hard to go through the captcha identification. I am kind of stuck